# Convert Java Mockito test to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito

I've got an issue converting the following working `Java` test to `Kotlin`

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {

    Mockito.when(parkIdMappingRepository.save(Mockito.any(ParkIdMapping.class))).thenAnswer(
        (Answer<ParkIdMapping>) invocation -> {
            ParkIdMapping mapping = invocation.getArgument(0);
            mapping.setId(100L);
            return mapping;
        }
    );
    ParkIdMapping mapping = parkIdMappingRepository.save(new ParkIdMapping("123"));

    assertEquals(new Long(100L), mapping.getId());
```

The conversion done by Intellij Idea to Kotlin results in:

```
@Test
public fun test_correctParkIdMappingGeneration() {

    Mockito.`when`(parkIdMappingRepository.save(Mockito.any(ParkIdMapping::class.java))).thenAnswer(
        { invocation -> // compiler error
            val mapping = invocation.getArgument(0)
            mapping.id = 100L
            mapping
        } as Answer<ParkIdMapping>
    )
    val mapping = parkIdMappingRepository.save(ParkIdMapping("123"))

    assertEquals(100L, mapping.id)
}
```

The line with the lambda parameter 'invocation', however, causes a compiler error:

> Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly .

I've tried to adjust the lambda like this

```
    Mockito.`when`(parkIdMappingRepository.save(Mockito.any(ParkIdMapping::class.java))).thenAnswer(
        { invocation: InvocationOnMock ->
            val mapping = invocation.getArgument(0) as ParkIdMapping
            mapping.id = 100L
            mapping
        } as Answer<ParkIdMapping>
    )
```

resulting in

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.foobar.ParkIdGenerationServiceTest$test_correctParkIdMappingGeneration$1 cannot be cast to org.mockito.stubbing.Answer
>
> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
>   Unfinished stubbing detected here:
>   -> at com.foobar.ParkIdGenerationServiceTest.testSomething(ParkIdGenerationServiceTest.kt:92)

The original intent is to modify the entity that is passed to the `save` method of the `repository` and return it. Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move unchecked cast to `Answer<ParkIdMapping>` to `getArgument` call.

Also, you need to add helper mock method. `Mockito.any()` returns null in it's verification function and the mock throws NPE because of Kotlin Null-safety feature.

Like this:

```
fun <T> any(): T {
    Mockito.any<T>()
    return uninitialized()
}

fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T
```

And the test will be:

```
@Test
public fun test_correctParkIdMappingGeneration() {

    Mockito.`when`<ParkIdMapping>(parkIdMappingRepository.save(any())).thenAnswer(
        { invocation -> // compiler error
            val mapping = invocation.getArgument<ParkIdMapping>(0)
            mapping.id = 100L
            mapping
        }
    )
    val mapping = parkIdMappingRepository.save(ParkIdMapping("123"))

    assertEquals(100L, mapping.id)
}
```

Future reading on Kotlin and Mockito interop: https://medium.com/@elye.project/befriending-kotlin-and-mockito-1c2e7b0ef791

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Now I've got a compiler error at `when` (first line in the test body) with "Type inference failed. Not enough information to infer parameter T in *fun <T:Any!> when (methodCall: T!) : OngoingStubbing<T!>! Please specify it explicitly" Did I miss anything?

Comment: Try to specify explicitly parameter of `when`:  `Mockito.\`when\`<ParkIdMapping>()`

Comment: Works like a charm. I felt free to update your snippet and mark your answer as resolved. Thanks a lot.